# ¿Como usar variable window.open (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una pagina en la cual ejecuto una ventana, lo que quiero hacer es comunicar la ventana padre con el hijo (enviar información desde el padre hacia el hijo), hice pruebas antes de implementarlo y funciono correctamente. 
lo que hice fue declarar una variable en la cual almacenaba la variable (`var miVentana = window.open.....` ), y se asignaba correctamente y pasaba información del padre al hijo sin problemas.

Al pasar el código para implementarlo en la pagina dejo de funcionar ya no asigna la variable `window.opener`.

Actualmente modifique mi código para almacenarlo en `localStore.setItem('nombrevar','valor')` y si se guarda pero como hago uso de la variable JavaScript me lo reconoce como objeto y no puedo hacer uso de `window.opener`

```
var miVentana;
function abrirHijo() 
{
  miVentana = window.open("indexDesarrolloContenido.php", "popupId", "location=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, resizable=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, width=500, height=500"); 
  sessionStorage.setItem("miVentana", miVentana);
}
.....
.....
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('miVentana');

data.document.getElementById('contenedorHijo').innerHTML=msg;
```

**¿Alguna recomendación sobre mi código?**

Comment: ¿ Porqué no encierras el valor en un objeto ? `sessionStorage.setItem( 'miventana', { id: miVentana } )`. Y accedes como `sessionStorage.getItem( 'miVentana' ).id`.

Comment: localStorage y sessionStorage no pueden guardar más que strings. Cuando guardas un objeto, en el mejor de los casos es el resultado de aplicar `JSON.stringify()` sobre éste.

Answer (score 1):

Debes convertir tu variable `miVentana` en String.

```
    miVentana = window.open("indexDesarrolloContenido.php", "popupId", 
    "location=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, resizable=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, 
width=500, height=500"); 

        sessionStorage.setItem("miVentana", JSON.stringify(miVentana));
        var recuperar=sessionStorage.getItem("miVentana");

        recuperar=JSON.parse(recuperar);
```